# Modifying JavaScript multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am seeing weird behavior when trying to modify a 2-dimensional array that represents a tic-tac-toe board. The first element of all the arrays are modified instead of the one.

```
// BEFORE: squares = [[null,null,null],[null,null,null],[null,null,null]]
squares[0][0] = 'X';
// AFTER: squares = [["X",null,null],["X",null,null],["X",null,null]]
```

I was able to fix the issue with the following code, but I am curious as to why this happens. Here is the working code:

```
let rowToModify = squares[yCoord].slice();
rowToModify[xCoord] = 'X';
squares[yCoord] = rowToModify;
```

Comment: Works just fine - https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/51110618/

Comment: Doing `squares[0][0] = 'X';` now way it can modify all the first elements. You might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You are likely initializing `squares` by using the same array three times. Something like this:

```
row = [null, null, null];
squares = [row, row, row];
```

However since `row` is all the same array, when you modify it, it will modify in all rows.

If you do:

```
squares = [[null,null,null], [null,null,null], [null,null,null]];
```

You will not get the problem.

The reason the other code works is because `slice` creates a new list, so you are no longer referencing the original list. Therefore it may be modified separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this `squares.map(a => a[0]='x')` using `Array#map`

```js
var squares = [
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null]
]
squares.map(a => a[0]='x')
console.log(squares)
```